# android background service get location

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, location

I have created an app where it is possible to start an background service. This service purpose is to monitor which app that is used on phone and save this data together with an timestamp and a coordinates to an SQLite on the phone.

The part which find the app and saves it with a time stamp works fine. But the part with the location doenst work. I have worked with locationslisteners before, but after many hours and many attempts I give up. 
Im not quit sure where to place my locationlistener? right now I have created a new inner class, but when i run it I get an error saying that I need to run Looper.prepare() but that doenst help. Then it says only one looper may be created per thread.

I feel now that no matter what i try something else is wrong and therefore I hope some of you guys can help me.

```
package com.dtu.applogger;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class loggerService extends Service{
DBAdapter dbadapter;
public MyLocationListener mMyLocationListener;
private NotificationManager mNM;
private int NOTIFICATION = 10002; //Any unique number for this notification
protected String latitude;
protected String longitude;
int counter= 0;
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL= 5000;
private Timer timer= new Timer();
public loggerService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}
private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = "TITLE";

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.call_log, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Service is running", text, contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    //showNotification();
    new DoBackgroundTask().execute();
    Toast.makeText(this,  "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}

private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask{
    String oldPackageName = "com.dtu.applogger";
    DBAdapter dbadapter = new DBAdapter(loggerService.this);

    public DoBackgroundTask() {

    }
    protected String findApp(){
        final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) loggerService.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) loggerService.this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

        if(!packageName.equals(oldPackageName) && !packageName.equals("com.dtu.applogger")){
            //save oldPackageName and packageName in DB     
            mMyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mMyLocationListener);
            String lat = latitude;
            String lng = longitude;

            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String txt = packageName + " : " + mydate;
            dbadapter.open();
            if(packageName.equals("com.android.launcher")){
                dbadapter.saveLog(mydate, oldPackageName, lat, lng);
            }else{
                dbadapter.saveLog(mydate, packageName, lat, lng);
            }

            dbadapter.close();
            oldPackageName = packageName;
            return txt;
        }
        if(packageName.equals(oldPackageName)){
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                String txt = findApp();
                if(txt != null){
                    Log.d("APP OPEN", "===== " + txt.toString());
                }
            Log.d("loggerService", String.valueOf(++counter));
            }
            }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

private class MyLocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6);
        latitude = Integer.toString(lat);
        longitude = Integer.toString(lng);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You make things too complicated, doInBackground is in a thread already, so the code below should be Ok.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
{
            while (!isCancelled())
            {
               String txt = findApp();
               if(txt != null)
               {
                    Log.d("APP OPEN", "===== " + txt.toString());
                }
                Log.d("loggerService", String.valueOf(++counter));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e1)
                {

                }
            }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thx for that, but that do not solve my problem with running another inner class in this case 'MyLocationListener'

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now by using implements LocationListener on 'DoOnBackgroundTasK' and removed the other inner class MyLocationListener. Though I had try that, but now it works. Though only using NETWORK_PROVIDER, if I use PASSIVE_PROVIDER i get an RuntimeException. What is the explanation to that?

I have pasted the code

```
 public class loggerService extends Service{
DBAdapter dbadapter;

private NotificationManager mNM;
private int NOTIFICATION = 10002; //Any unique number for this notification
protected String latitude;
protected String longitude;
int counter= 0;
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL= 5000;
private Timer timer= new Timer();
public loggerService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}
private void showNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = "TITLE";

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.call_log, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Service is running", text, contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    //showNotification();
    new DoBackgroundTask().execute();
    Toast.makeText(this,  "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}

private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask implements LocationListener{
    String oldPackageName = "com.dtu.applogger";
    DBAdapter dbadapter = new DBAdapter(loggerService.this);

    public DoBackgroundTask() {

    }
    protected String findApp(){

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) loggerService.this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

        if(!packageName.equals(oldPackageName) && !packageName.equals("com.dtu.applogger")){
            //save oldPackageName and packageName in DB     
            String lat = latitude;
            String lng = longitude;

            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            String txt = packageName + " : " + mydate;
            dbadapter.open();
            if(packageName.equals("com.android.launcher")){
                dbadapter.saveLog(mydate, oldPackageName, lat, lng);
                Log.d("LATITUDE ", lat.toString());
                Log.d("LONGITUDE ", lng.toString());
            }else{
                dbadapter.saveLog(mydate, packageName, lat, lng);
            }

            dbadapter.close();
            oldPackageName = packageName;
            return txt;
        }
        if(packageName.equals(oldPackageName) || packageName.equals("com.dtu.applogger")){
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) loggerService.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

//
//REQUEST LOCATION UPDATE WORKS WITH NETWORK BUT NOT WITH PASSIVE???
//

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()){
                String txt = findApp();
                if(txt != null){
                    Log.d("APP OPEN", "===== " + txt.toString());
                }
            Log.d("loggerService", String.valueOf(++counter));
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1){
            }
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}


public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```